# Program Interaction and testing via bash script

Tags: c++, bash

I've just completed the coding section of simple homework assignment for my C++ class.  The second part of the assignment requires us to verify our code's input validation.  (The program takes several different values as inputs from a user and prints those values to a file)

I was hoping that I could use bash script for this.  Is there any way to use bash script to run and interact with a program?  How can I put the program's output into a variable (note that program has a series of input requests and outputs).

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at tush: http://darius.livejournal.com/42878.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build on @Travis' answer, create two files: one holds your inputs (`input.txt`) and one holds the expected output (`expected_output.txt`). Then do the following:

```
./myprogram <input.txt >output.txt
diff output.txt expected_output.txt
```

If the `diff` command has any output, there's a problem.

Comment: If you use `diff -u` to generate the difference, the output might be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do much of this with a shell script but you might want to consider using some other testing tools instead like [CppUnit](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/lastest/cppunit_cookbook.html) or [`expect`](http://expect.nist.gov/).